# Regular Expressions in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am writting a script that parses through a text, the text has no structure at all, meaning that what i am willing to extract has no specific structure.
the script must use REGEX to find the quatinty of specific articles:

```
$article ="balls","dolls"
```

normal structure =

1. "3 balls"
2. "2 balls and 6 dolls"

I can retrieve the values with a regex like this `((\d+)."+$article+"|$)`. this works only if the quantity value in near the article.

but if the value isn't well i end up with nothing. eg.

1. 3 balls and dolls
   or
2. 3 red balls

So i guess a good way to do this would be find $article and then lookback for any integer value.
I worked out this regex `(?=.*"+$article+")([\d\.]+)` but i can not make it to just look for the left first match.
any suggestions.

Thanxs a bunch!!!

Comment: You want to do nlp with regexes alone?

Comment: Well because I am not a regex expert this could be very messy, I guess the easiest way would be using Powershell libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Download [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).  This is a great interface for developing RegEx queries

Step 2 - i haven't had a chance to play with this query yet, but step 1 will help